# How do I input values from Python lists into an HTML table?

Tags: python, html, list, input, html-table

I have two lists in python that I would like to input into two separate columns in an HTML table. What would the code look like on the python end of things and what would it look like for html? 
This is what I have in python now:

```
        giver = []
        recipient = []
        giver.append(name)
        recipient.append(match)

    return render_template("created.html", givers=givers, recpients=recipients)
```

And this is what I have in HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Giver</th>
            <th>Recipient</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ givers }}</td>
            <td>{{ recipients }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: create one list (ie. using `zip()`) and send it to template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one list

```
    data = []

    data.append( (name, match) )

return render_template("created.html", data=data)
```

and use it in template

```
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```